# Why is the order of $X_{2n}$ is at most $6$ where $X_{2n}=\langle x,y\mid x^{n}=y^{2}=1,xy=yx^{2}\rangle$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am reading the book Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote.

I am at the begining of the book, and I got to a section about generators
and relations.

The book gives the definition 
$$
X_{2n}:=\langle x,y\mid x^{n}=y^{2}=1,xy=yx^{2}\rangle
$$

and shows that $x^{3}=e$.

It is then stated that $X_{2n}$ is at most of order $6$.

Can someone please explain why ? I guess that the $6$ comes from
$6=2\cdot3$ where $2,3$ are the orders of $y,x$ accordingly, but
I don't understand how.

Comment: @njguliyev - Can you say why ? I can only show it in the abelian case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any element of $X_{2n}$ can be written as $x^ay^b$ because when starting from a general element, i.e. a product of $x,x^{-1},y,y^{-1}$, we can first of all replace $x^{-1}$ with $x^{n-1}$ (or in fact $x^2$ according to the preliminary result) and $y^{-1}$ with $y$. Next, we can use $yx=x^2y$ to arrive at a word where $y$ is never followed by $x$.
Now from $x^3=y²=1$ we find that it suffices to consider $0\le a\le 2$ and $0\le b\le 1$, i.e. $$X_{2n}=\{1,x,x^2,y,xy,x^2y\}.$$ (Note that the set on the right might in fact have less than $6$ elements).